# List other remote branches after checking out specific branch

Tags: git, branch, clone, git-clone

I clones a branch with `git clone --branch=<MyRemoteBranch> --depth 50 https://<MyUserName>@bitbucket.org/<MyRepo>.git`

When I use `branch -r` the only output I get is:

```
 origin/<MyRemoteBranch>
```

Is there a way I can get it to start showing the rest of my remote branches so I can fetch other branches? I want to fetch origin/HEAD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clone%5D+shallow+remote+branches

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html). This lists all remote references and the corresponding commit IDs, making it easy to checkout to a specific commit if necessary. `HEAD` is also shown.

By default, the list includes tags, but this can be disabled.